# How to properly load a MESH file in CGAL

Tags: cgal

I have been trying to load a .mesh file using the following lines of code but it seems not to load the mesh properly, only its nodes, as evident from writing the read input back to a .mesh file.

```
C3t3 c3t3;
std::ifstream in("input.mesh", std::ios_base::in|std::ios_base::binary);
CGAL::build_triangulation_from_file<C3t3::Triangulation, true>(in, c3t3.triangulation(), true);

std::ofstream medit_file("output.mesh");
c3t3.output_to_medit(medit_file);
```

Comment: If you use the master branch of CGAL (or starting from the upcoming CGAL 5.6) you can use the function [read_MEDIT()](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/SMDS_3/group__PkgSMDS3IOFunctions.html#gae568272186821b0b236257819dbf55db).

Comment: That's nice that it will be officially supported from next version onward. Thanks!

Comment: @sloriot I have tested with the new function and the issue remains. The output is giving the error "Error in add_facet_to_incident_cells_map" before giving a segmentation fault. The .mesh file I am trying to load was generated by CGAL itself. I have made the mesh file available this [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f095b06e268879212cc60c78bfdf5ea820221029064830/48c963).

Comment: I've create the following [issue](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/6997) and assigned the author of the function. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Could you please do the same check as for the other thread (using the branch of https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/7062), and if it does not, re-upload the input somewhere more lasting like a gist since the previous link has expired.

Comment: The issue remains. You will find the file at [link](https://gist.github.com/Another-Anonymous-User/7b628cf1f010dfcd143449bc4ef09ae3). In case it helps, so far I have only gotten this issue with some files saved with output_periodic_mesh_to_medit.

Comment: If the file is from a periodic mesh, there's usually non-manifoldness in the output. Currently you can't use `read_MEDIT` because it does not tolerate non-manifoldness, and you need to `build_triangulation_from_file()` and use the "true" flag for the third Boolean parameter (`allow_non_manifold`). I can read your file with this. I will improve the `read_MEDIT` function such that you can specify non-manifoldness tolerance via named parameters.

Comment: Note that there is currently no way to reconstruct a valid *periodic* triangulation from a MEDIT file: even using the non-manifold option, you will successfully read it, but you cannot use it for anything other than visualization.